# Catching EndpointNotFoundException with RESTful client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, exception

I implemented simple RestFull client:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription));
                }

                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                return responseData;
            }
```

This example works fine, but I wanna catch "EndpointNotFoundException", when my service is not available. Now I catch System.Net.WebException.

Line below:

```
  request.GetResponse()
```

is the line which falls and line which according to .NET specification throws:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException:
 System.Net.ProtocolViolationException:
 System.NotSupportedException:
 System.Net.WebException:
```

How I can refactor my RestFull client to catch "EndpointNotFoundException" or to know when my server is not avaliable?

Comment: Does `WebException` contains Http Status codes?  Wouldn't an endpoint not found be equivalent to a 404?

Comment: You could inspect the `StatusCode` property of the `HttpWebResponse` as well - if it is `HttpStatusCode.NotFound` then it's a 404 error.

Comment: If he expects EndpointNotFound then he will not get a response to get the code from.

Answer (score 1):

Is this necessary for you to use WebRequest class as your REST client?  Please correct me if Im wrong, but MSDN does not say this method throws the exception you want (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx)
If you can classes other than WebRequest then I would suggest:

1. Using WebChannelFactory class like this

```cs
Uri serviceUri = new Uri(yourUriString);
WebChannelFactory<IYourService> factory =
new WebChannelFactory<IYourService>(serviceUri);
IYourService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
proxy.MethodFromYourService();
```

**or**

2. Create your proxy manually and make it inherit from ClientBase class like this:

```cs
 public class ClientClass :ClientBase<IYourService>,IYourService
    {
        public string SampleGet()
        {
           return base.Channel.SampleGet();
        }
    }
```

I have checked and both ways gave me the EndpointNotFoundException.

EDIT. ClientBase requires a system.serviceModel section in your web config to work properly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my method does not throw exception I need. I wrote it in question. Thank you for your answer, but for this example I need service interface (class file) from my client, do I ?. I cannot provide it, I have only address (uri) for GET method which I could call.

Comment: Well, service interface is your service contract - something that is essential to WCF services AND EndpointNotFound is a WCF exception. I dont think you can expect it to be thrown from classes that do not rely on WCF mechanisms. Also - its a common practice to put your service contracts into separate DLL that can be referenced on both client and host so your client doesn't have to know anything about the service classes.

Comment: I completely agree, it would be the best solution if I have service contract. Unfortunately I cannot provide ti for now, because contract might be changed by the time (new methods could be added and so on), and client do not want to share it.

Answer (score 0):

capture the responsecode and determine if it is a 404 or 5XX errors.  Upon each error, raise a new exception based on the response code.

I would put the response code into an switch statement, and do different actions and raise different exceptions for each response code if needed.

Comment: Status code 404 (NotFound) I get only when I put wrong URL to the service method, when service is started. When my service is not available at all (I made RestFull service on the same machine for the purpose of testing) I get message "ConnectFailure" or even "Timeout" exception. According to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es54hw8e(v=vs.110).aspx, I need "ProtocolError" if I want to discover httpResponse.StatusCode.